# how to handle different size of input data using Pytorch built in neural network

Tags: pytorch, neural-network

I build a simple pytorch model as below. However, I receive error message that mat1 and mat2 size are not aligned. How do I tweek the code to allow the flexibility of different dimension of data?

```
class simpleNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, **input_dim, hidden_size, num_classes**):
        """
        :param input_dim: input feature dimension
        :param hidden_size: hidden dimension
        :param num_classes: total number of classes
        """
        super(TwoLayerNet, self).__init__()
        
        # hidden layer
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_size)
        # Second fully connected layer that outputs our 10 labels
        self.output = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)
      
    def forward(self, x):
        out = None
      
        x = self.hidden(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        x = self.output(x)


        out = x
```

trying to build a toy neural network using Pytorch.

Answer (score 0):

For your neural network to work, your output from your previous layer should be equal to your input for next layer, since its a code snippet for just your architecture without the initializations code, I cannot tell what you can simplify, not having equals in transition is not a good practice though. However, you can use reshape function from torch to make your output of previous layer equal to your next layer to make it work as a brute force method. Refer to: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html